# How to add more photos to AWS Sagemaker Labelling job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

We wish to add more photos to the AWS Sagemaker Labelling job. We tried adding the photo's directly to the s3 path and editing the input manifest file but they don't seem to update on the Labelling task. Is there any workaround for it?

Reference used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-input-data-input-manifest.html

On a side note: Is there any reference for chaining the jobs, since the documentation on Amazon is confusing and there are no practical examples out there either.